# How to retrieve all wikipedia articles containing at least one table?

Tags: wikipedia-api, opensearch

The API doesn't seem to be very clear in how to retrieve all articles containing a "wikitable" class.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because there is no such API. You can try [searching](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) for `class="wikitable"`.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are unstructured and can appear in unexpected places, such as  manually aligning images.  You can try the searching [`insource:" class=wikitable"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=insource%3A%22%20class%3Dwikitable%22&title=Special:Search&profile=default), as Tgr suggests.